# Switch statement error? Error: The local variable medName may not have been initialized

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and seem to be struggling with switch statements. It all looks correct to me, can't figure it out. All help is deeply appreciated.

```
 public static String chooseMedicine()
      {
        System.out.println("Choose a medicine to prescribe for the patient.");
        int medicineNbr = keyboard.nextInt();
        String medicineString = determineMedicine(medicineNbr);
        System.out.println(medicineString + ". Good choice.");
        return medicineString;
      }

      public static String determineMedicine(int medicine)
      { 
        String medName;
        switch(medicine)
        { 
          case 1: medName = MEDICINE_1;
          break;
          case 2: medName = MEDICINE_2;
          break;
          case 3: medName = MEDICINE_3;
          break;
          case 4: medName = MEDICINE_4;
          break;
          case 5: medName = MEDICINE_5;
          break;
          default: System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-5");
          break;
        }
        return medName; **//Error: The local variable medName may not have been initialized**
      }
```

Comment: `default` doesn't do anything to `medName` like many of the answer suggests you can handle it there or assign a default value to `medName`

Comment: Also you should probably indent `break;` but that's unrelated to the error

Comment: What part of "The local variable medName may not have been initialized" do you *not* understand? That's the clearest error message that I've seen in my entire life. You see the local variable `medName`, right? You hopefully know what "initialized" means. When it is declared, it is not initialized. Now, if you think about what happens with `medName` when the user enters `42`, you should understand why `medNames` might end up uninitialized in the end. Sorry, the error messages won't get any nicer than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **default** case you don't allocate any value to `medName`, but you access it. Thus the error. If you want to access it make sure to allocate it in every branch:

```
default: System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-5");
    medName = "Unknown";
break;
```

Or throw an exception if that branch should not be possible to reach:

```
default: throw new IllegalStateException("Number must be between 1 and 5");
```

Or maybe better, check the inputs of the method right at start:

```
if (medicine < 1 || medicine > 5) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number must be between 1 and 5");
}
```

and then throw an `AssertionError` in the default case, which represents a location that must never be reachable (and if, it represents a bug in the code):

```
default: throw new AssertionError("Argument check did not work, something is wrong");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't think to think of it that way.

Answer (score 1):

in case you hit the default case, your medName variable will have no value. You should set the value of your medName variable to something that let's the caller know the medicine does not exist for the given parameter passed in

```
default: 
    medName = "Invalid Medicine Value";
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-5");
break;
```

You could also simply initialize the variable medName to a string and also avoid your problem

```
String medName = "NULL Medicine";
switch(medicine)...
```